# array_sum has not return 0

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
    // PHP Version 5.2.9
    $arr = array(75.6, 75.6, -226.8,  75.6);
    var_dump(array_sum($arr)); // float(-2.84217094304E-14) 
?>
```

Result is not `0`. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: are you proposing a calculation problem or storage issue here plz?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This not the problem of `array_sum`, `echo 75.6+75.6-226.8+75.6;` also give you the same result. This is the problem that how computer treats the float number. See [here(Floating point)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for more information.